# Насколько правильно реализован класс для датчика в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, инспекция-кода

Есть датчик, который выдаёт и записывает значение по шине SPI при обращении к определённым номерам регистров. Мне хотелось бы попрактиковаться в ООП и написать небольшую библиотеку для этого датчика, чтобы пользователь, который будет ей пользоваться не беспокоился о том, что происходит внутри, и просто по одной команде получал или записывал значения в датчик. Это моя первая практика в ООП, поэтому хотелось бы узнать, насколько правильно написана программа, где допустил ошибки, что можно сделать лучше или по-другому.

```
import spidev 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# ADIS 16490 USER self.regISTER MEMORY MAP

_PAGE_ID = 0x00 # Same for all pages

# PAGE 0x00
_TEMP_OUT = 0x0E
_Z_GYRO_LOW = 0x18
_Z_GYRO_OUT = 0x1A
_Z_ACCL_LOW = 0x24
_Z_ACCL_OUT = 0x26
_PROD_ID = 0x7E  

# PAGE 0x01 Reserved

# PAGE 0x03
_DEC_RATE = 0x0C

IRQ = 6  # GPIO connect to data redy
spi = spidev.SpiDev()  # Создаем объект SPI
spi.open(0, 0)  # Выбор номера порта и номера устройства(CS) шины SPI
spi.max_speed_hz = 15000000  # Задаём максимальную скорость работы шины SPI
spi.mode = 3  # Выбор режима работы SPI (от 0 до 3)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Выбор режима нумерации выводов GPIO
GPIO.setup(IRQ, GPIO.IN)  # Инициализация GPIO6 на ввод


# Функция читающая данные по шине SPI
def _spi_read(spi, reg):  # Функция считывания данных по SPI
    send = [0]*2  # Создаём список из двух элементов
    # В 0 ячейку списка записываем адрес, который указываем в параметре reg
    send[0] = reg 
    spi.writebytes(send)  # Отправляем байты по шине SPI
    # Считываем 2 байта по шине SPI. В итоге получаем список из двух значений [X, Y]
    resp = spi.readbytes(2)
    # Сдвигаем 8 бит ячейки 0 влево, затем используем лог. сложение с ячейкой 1
    resp = ((resp[0] << 8) | resp[1])
    return resp


# Функция записывающая данные по шине SPI
def _spi_write(spi, reg, value):  # Функция записи данных по SPI
    send = [0]*2  # Создаём список из двух элементов
    # В 0 ячейку списка записываем адрес, который указываем в параметре reg и с помощью лог.ИЛИ указываем старший бит на запись
    send[0] = 0x80 | reg
    send[1] = value  # В 1 ячейку отправляем данные которые нужно записать
    spi.writebytes(send)  # Отправляем байты по шине SPI


# Дескриптор позволяющий получать и записывать значения в атрибуты класса
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # if value < 0:
        #     raise ValueError('Cannot be negative.')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name


# Основной класс датчика
class ADIS_16490:
    temp_out = Descriptor()
    z_gyro_32 = Descriptor()
    z_accl_32 = Descriptor()
    decrate = Descriptor()

    def __init__(self): 
        """Check the ADIS was found, read the coefficients and enable the sensor"""
        # Check device ID.
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(IRQ, GPIO.FALLING) # Ждём уровень спадающего фронта (по документации)
        _spi_write(spi, _PAGE_ID, 0x00)  # Переключаемся на 1 страницу
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(IRQ, GPIO.FALLING)  
        # Считываем ID датчика, если не совпадает, то вызываем ошибку
        ADIS_PROD_ID = _spi_read(spi, _PROD_ID) 
        if  ADIS_PROD_ID != 16490:  
            raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to find ADIS 16490! Chip ID {ADIS_PROD_ID}")        

    # Метод для чтения данных по номеру адреса регистра
    def _get(self, reg):
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(IRQ, GPIO.FALLING) 
        self.value = _spi_read(spi, reg)  # Считываем значение
        return self.value
   
    # Метод для записи данных по номеру адреса регистра
    def _set(self, reg, value):
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(IRQ, GPIO.FALLING) 
        _spi_write(spi, reg, value) # Записываем данные в регистр

    # Метод для изменения номера страниц датчика
    def _select_page(self, page):
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(IRQ, GPIO.FALLING) 
        _spi_write(spi, _PAGE_ID, page)  # Переключаемся на страницу  

    # Метод для объединения 16 битных чисел в 32 бита
    def _unity(self, high, low):  
        bit32 = ((high << 16) | (low & 0xFFFF))
        return bit32

    # Метод проверки значения на знак
    def _check(self, val, bits):  
        # Если отрицательное, то переводим в дополнительный код
        if((val & (1 << (bits-1))) != 0):  
            val = val - (1 << bits)
        return val   

    # Метод для вывода температуры
    def temp(self):  
        self._select_page(0x00)
        self.temp_out = self._get(_TEMP_OUT)
        self.temp_out = self._check(self.temp_out, 16)  # Проверим число на знак
        return 0.01429 * self.temp_out + 25  # Применяем формулу расчёта температуры из datasheet

    # Метод для вывода значений гироскопа оси Z
    def z_gyro(self):
        self._select_page(0x00)
        self.z_gyro_low = self._get(_Z_GYRO_LOW)
        self.z_gyro_out = self._get(_Z_GYRO_OUT)
        self.z_gyro_32 = self._unity(self.z_gyro_out, self.z_gyro_low)
        self.z_gyro_32 = self._check(self.z_gyro_32, 32)  # Проверим число на знак
        return self.z_gyro_32 * 0.005/65536
    
    # Метод для вывода значений акселерометра оси Z
    def z_accl(self): 
        self._select_page(0x00)
        self.z_accl_low = self._get(_Z_ACCL_LOW)
        self.z_accl_out = self._get(_Z_ACCL_OUT)
        self.z_accl_32 = self._unity(self.z_accl_out, self.z_accl_low)
        self.z_accl_32 = self._check(self.z_accl_32, 32)  # Проверим число на знак
        return self.z_accl_32 * 0.5/65536

    
    # Метод для чтения параметра декрейта
    # Количество значений в 1 секунду = 4250 / (dec_rate + 1)
    def read_decrate(self):
        self._select_page(0x03)
        self.decrate = self._get(_DEC_RATE)
        return self.decrate  

    # Метод для изменения параметра декрейта
    def set_decrate(self, value):
        #Необходимо полученное число разделить на 2 части по 8 бит каждое
        decrate_low = value & 0xff
        decrate_high = (value >> 8) & 0xff
        self._select_page(0x03)
        self._set(_DEC_RATE, decrate_low)
        self._set(_DEC_RATE+1, decrate_high)

sensor = ADIS_16490()  # Создание экземпляра класса
sensor.set_decrate(5) # Установка декрейта

# Вывод параметров в консоль
while True:
    temp = sensor.temp()
    z_gyro = sensor.z_gyro()
    z_accl = sensor.z_accl()
    decrate = sensor.read_decrate()
    print(temp)
    print(z_gyro)
    print(z_accl)
    print(decrate)
    time.sleep(1)
```

На данном этапе программа работает и значения выводятся в консоль.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120293/discussion-on-question-by-leach------).